# Cassandra c# driver ServerErrorException while executing create cql statement

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am getting Cassandra task timeout error while executing

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriber.packagestats (packageid text PRIMARY KEY, numaccounts counter);

### LOGS

> Cassandra.ServerErrorException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                        at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)
>                        at Cassandra.Session.Execute(IStatement statement)

Query Consistency level is set to **ALL**

Used Cassandra c# driver version is **3.0.5**

It was working fine until now but suddenly it starts throwing the exception , I also tried to increase the timeout upto 1 minute but still the problem persists.

Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Check Cassandra `system.log`

Comment: does the command work in cqlsh?

Comment: @xmas79 yes it works, I could create it manually locally using devcenter.

Comment: `Cassandra.ServerErrorException` means that there was an unexpected exception server side, as said by @AshrafulIslam, you should check the system.log file for the server side error log.

Comment: I suspect that schema update/create may be triggering race condition issues in the Cassandra version that we use (3.0.5).

Schema changes in Cassandra are every sensitive and error prone. Strong consistency was only added in version 4 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10699.
Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41269542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that schema update/create was triggering race condition issues in the Cassandra version that we use (3.0.5). Schema changes in Cassandra are every sensitive and error prone. Strong consistency was only added in version 4 [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10699](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10699)
Look here: [stackoverflow.com/a/41269542](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41269542)

So I **upgraded to version 4** and it solved the problem.