# Nodejs + Cassandra driver --- getting error 'unconfigured table' when trying to create materialized view

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm running on Nodejs 8.9 & the latest Datastax Cassandra driver.
Upon service startup I'm executing 2 queries, one which creates a table (in case is does not exist) and the other creates a materialized view.

The table creation query passes without any issues, but when I execute the query for the materialized view, I get 'unconfigured table' error.

I've tried to debug it, and saw (via terminal) that indeed the table does not appear in Cassandra after the query executes, it appears only after I stop the service entirely. I've tried closing the connection after creating the table and re-creating it, but I still get the same error.

This is how I execute the query:

```
try{
     let respose = await client.execute(query, null, queryOptions);    
   }catch(error){
     throw (error);
   }
```

Changing the CONSISTENCY_POLICY did not help either.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this should happen when the schema isn't in agreement between all nodes.  By default driver should wait 10 seconds until agreement is reached.  This time is controlled by `protocolOptions.maxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds` parameter of the `Client` - try to increase this parameter & try.

Also, you need to check that your cluster is in agreement - please run `nodetool describecluster` [as described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsDescribeCluster.html).

Comment: I see, does it apply even if the CONSISTENCY_POLICY is set to one?

Comment: Schema changes are separate from read/write operations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248615/set-consistency-level-for-cassandra-ddl for more details

Comment: Why increase it? and not decrease it?
Also, maybe I should just set my service to wait a few seconds before attempting to create the materialized view?

Comment: Sometimes gossip doesn't happen fast enough... Usually, for queries with DDL operations response have special flag that indicates schema change - in this case internal function `_waitForSchemaAgreement` is called that waits max specified time.

Comment: I've tried to increase the vault to 20 seconds, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce it... what version of driver and Cassandra do you use?

Comment: NodeJs cassandra-driver v.3.4.1. Cassandra v.3.10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165625/discussion-between-david-faiz-and-alex-ott).